# Whiptail does not respond to [ESC]?

Tags: bash, shell, dialog, whiptail

In a system which does not have `dialog`, I was trying to use `whiptail` instead, however, I found that the current `whiptail` does not respond to the <kbd>ESC</kbd>. My question is:

Any other way to escape a `whiptail` dialog?

```
Ubuntu 14, Konsole, whiptail (newt): 0.52.15
```

Comment: Which system? which version of whiptail? You might also need to revise your terminal emulation settings so that the ESC is passed through.

Comment: What terminal emulator?

Comment: Edited. By the way, pressing in `dialog` is totally fine. So I think ESC is able to be passed through.